# Спойлер JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пис всем. Помогите доработать спойлер
Пример на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/7wzum/1/)

- Вопрос №1: Как убрать плавное
     выдвижение спойлера?
- Вопрос №2: Как сделать содержимое спойлера
     подгружаемым только тогда, когда
     спойлер открывается, а не подгружается при
     загрузки страницы.

---

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.spoiler_links').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body').toggle('normal');
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

1. `toggle('normal');` заменить на `toggle();`
2. При клике отправлять Ajax запрос на сервер

Незачто.

Comment: Не работает(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/7wzum/3/

Comment: Извиняюсь. Спс.

Comment: [вот для ленивых, пример с ajax](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/7wzum/4/)